# How to select each element of a group and convert all of them into a single row?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I have this tables: ORDERS and ORDERS_DETAILS.

The fields in each table are:

---

ORDERS: id_order

ORDERS_DETAILS: id_order, sub_total

---

ORDERS_DETAILS has a maximum of 4 rows.

I need to show each order, joined with all its orders_details in one simple row. 
Something like this:

*id_order , sub_total_1 , sub_total_2 , sub_total_3 , sub_total_4*

For example, from 2 orders

ORDER: Has only 2 items 
{1 , 2}

---

ORDERS_DETAILS: Has 4 items for each order

{ 10.2 , 1, 10.2 , 20   }----->from order_id=1

{ 5 , 7.6, 3.2 , 9   }-----> from order_id=2

the result:

*id_order , sub_total_1 , sub_total_2 , sub_total_3 , sub_total_4*

{ 1 , 10.2 , 1 , 10.2 , 20   }

{ 2 , 5 , 7.6 , 3.2 , 9   }

I don't know how to select each element of each order and convert it in a column.
I was trying with this, but when I fill the datagrid, it doesnt work:

```
var orders= from od in db.Orders_Details                           
                        group od by od.order_id into order
                        select new
                        {
                           Key=order.Key,
                           SubTotal_1=order.ToArray()[0].sub_total,
                           SubTotal_2=order.ToArray()[1].sub_total,
                           SubTotal_3=order.ToArray()[2].sub_total,
                           SubTotal_4=order.ToArray()[3].sub_total,
                        };
```

Comment: What is mean by does't work? DataGrid on which platform exactly? If using DataGridView in WinForm, add ToList() then supply to DataSource can do.

Comment: Also the ordering of `Orders_Details` not guarantee to be SubToal_1 to 4 in the result, which may cause unwanted results

Comment: I don't use linq-to-sql, but the raw sql solution is the LEFT JOIN the order_details table into the query four times.

Comment: @Eric Yes I'm using DataGridView in WinForm but when I fill the datagrid I get this exception: "The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entities."

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn Is there another way to do it?

Comment: That _is_ the way you do it in raw SQL. You need to write the linq-to-sql code to emulate that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like:

```
 var orders = (from od in db.Orders
   select new
   {
      od.order_id,
      Order_Details = od.Orders_Details.OrderBy(c=>c.order_detail_id).ToList()
   }).ToList().Select(c => new
       {
           c.order_id,
           SubTotal_1 = c.Order_Details.Count > 0 ? c.Order_Details[0].sub_total : (decimal?)null,
           SubTotal_2 = c.Order_Details.Count > 1 ? c.Order_Details[1].sub_total : (decimal?)null,
           SubTotal_3 = c.Order_Details.Count > 2 ? c.Order_Details[2].sub_total : (decimal?)null,
           SubTotal_4 = c.Order_Details.Count > 3 ? c.Order_Details[3].sub_total : (decimal?)null
       }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is exactly what you want,
but here is one way you can do it with LINQ.

Hope this helps.

```
public class Order
{
    public int orderId;
}

public class OrderDetails
{
    public int orderId;
    public double subTotal;
}

[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    var orders = new List<Order> {
        new Order{orderId = 1} , 
        new Order{orderId = 2}
    };

    var orderDetails = new List<OrderDetails> {
        new OrderDetails{orderId = 1 , subTotal = 10.1} , 
        new OrderDetails{orderId = 1 , subTotal = 1} , 
        new OrderDetails{orderId = 1 , subTotal = 10.2} , 
        new OrderDetails{orderId = 1 , subTotal = 20} , 
        new OrderDetails{orderId = 2 , subTotal = 5},
        new OrderDetails{orderId = 2 , subTotal = 7.6},
        new OrderDetails{orderId = 2 , subTotal = 3.2},
        new OrderDetails{orderId = 2 , subTotal = 9}
    };

    var result = orderDetails.
        GroupBy(o => new
        {
            orderId = o.orderId
        },
        (key, items) => new
        {
            orderId = key.orderId,
            subTotals = items.Select(p => p.subTotal).ToList()
        }).
        ToList();
}
```